# Are all Hausdorff fractals also box counting fractals?

Tags: measure-theory, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, chaos-theory, hausdorff-measure

The Hausdorff dimension of a set $A$ is always lesser or equal than its boxcounting dimension.

$$
\mathrm{dim}_\mathcal{H}(A)\leq\mathrm{dim}_\mathcal{B}(A)
$$

More precisely lesser or equal than its lower boxcounting dimension.

If the set $A$ is fulfills the open set condition or is self-similar, the two dimensions are equal.

But if $A$ does not, is it possible that only one of those dimensions is fractal?

For example, $\mathrm{dim}_\mathcal{H}(A)=1$ while $\mathrm{dim}_\mathcal{B}(A)>1$ or $\mathrm{dim}_\mathcal{B}(A)=1$ while $\mathrm{dim}_\mathcal{H}(A)<1$.

Comment: Yes, this is very much possible. See my answer to [Is there a gap between the Hausdorff and the lower Minkowski dimensions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265756/is-there-a-gap-between-the-hausdorff-and-the-lower-minkowski-dimensions) for more extreme examples.

Comment: Incidentally, an interesting result (that has been generalized and strengthened in many ways) is that MOST compact sets (in the Baire category sense, using the Hausdorff metric) in ${\mathbb R}^{n}$ have Hausdorff dimension $0$ and box dimension $n.$ So in a certain sense, pretty much every compact set has an extreme version of the behavior you're looking for! Note that by using examples that are compact sets, the sets in particular are closed, so these examples avoid taking the easy way out by using a countable dense set (which trivially have Hausdorff dimension $0$ and box dimension $n).$

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. What is the name of this result? I will check out the references you mentioned on mathoverflow. I am very happy that there even is a construction given to those sets!

Comment: There are several books that give such examples --- Edgar's, Falconer's, Tricot's, etc. --- but if you're looking online and want something not super-advanced, try googling something like ["box dimension" "Hausdorff dimension" "cantor set" Bachelor "thesis"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22box+dimension%22+%22Hausdorff+dimension%22+%22cantor+set%22+Bachelor+%22thesis%22). For example, [this thesis](http://dc.ewu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1181&context=theses) seems to be very accessible, although I can't tell off-hand what kind of strict inequality examples it has.

Comment: If you send me your email address (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13130/dave-l-renfro?tab=profile) for my email address), I can send you a scanned copy of a Masters thesis (not on the internet) that has a lot of examples worked out in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Everything, within the bounds $0\le \dim_H\le \dim_B\le n$ (for subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is possible. I'll give two examples in $\mathbb{R}^2$, which can be generalized.

Example 1: $A=\{(x, y): 0\le y\le 1, x\in \{1/1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots\}\}$. This is the union of countably many line segments $\{1/k\}\times [0,1]$. Since the Hausdorff dimension is countably stable, $\dim_H A = 1$. On the other hand, $\dim_B A = 3/2$. Indeed, if we cover $A$ by boxes of size $\epsilon$, then doubling the size each box we cover the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $A$. This neighborhood contains the rectangle $[0,\sqrt{\epsilon}]\times [0,1]$ because when $1/k < \sqrt{\epsilon}$, the distance between $1/k$ and $1/(k+1)$ becomes less than $\epsilon$. Since the area of this rectangle is $\sqrt{\epsilon}$, and each $\epsilon$-square has area $\epsilon^2$ it follows that the number of boxes is $\ge C\epsilon^{-3/2}$. A matching upper bound can be shown by using $\epsilon^{-3/2}$ boxes to cover the aforementioned rectangle, and about as many boxes to cover the remaining $\epsilon^{-1/2}$ line segments individually.

Example 2: pick a Cantor-type set $C\subset [0,1]$ of Hausdorff dimension $1/2$, and let $A=\{(x, y): y\in C, x\in \{1/1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots\}\}$. Again by countable stability, $\dim_H A = 1/2$. On the other hand, $\dim_B A=1$ which is left as an exercise.